# Why is my Jest/Stencil test environment not working?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, stenciljs

my npm version is 6.14.15

Now I want to run a simple Jest test.
But I get following error:
Test suite failed to run

> TypeError: core_1.Component is not a function

But actually it happens with all Decorators. Like @Prop , @State , @Component etc.

So what I did for my unit test to work I just removed all these decorators from my .tsx File. And finally the unit test worked.(It pretends to run throught, but I have the feeling the test is doing nothing because if a change the expected value to nonsense it still gives me agreen check. It seems to stop in jest-intellij-util.js) Of course the unit test wouldn't need the prop etc anyway because unit test means test in isolation.

But yeah I really want to know how I can fix my test enviroment so it works even with decorators .

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds like your Stencil environment is not set up properly or you are not running tests properly. Have you followed the Stencil docs? https://stenciljs.com/docs/testing-overview

Answer (score -1):

try this code in a .spec.tsx file

````
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';
import { h } from '@stencil/core';

describe('my-component', () => {
  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      template: ()=><my-component></my-component>,
    });
    expect(page.root.shadowRoot).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});```
````